# My APK generated with android studio does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework, apk

I developed an application by means of the framework Ionic and I now wish to compile it with android studio. The application works very well on browser and on android emulator but when I compile it in release and when I install this APK on my Smartphone, files are not loaded.

Here is the screen which shows me my Smartphone (incorrect):

[image]

And here is the screen which shows me the browser and the emulator android (correct):

[image]

The lines that show me the application (screen incorrect) are supposed to be the buttons of the menu (right part of the screen).

Have you an idea of my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Ionic Framework, you should use the tools they provide to build your application.

In your project, you can type the following command : `ionic run android` (it builds the app and run it in the emulator or on your device if it's connected to your computer. Do not forget to enable android debugging in the developer options).

See documentation : http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html